# Play sound before end of Countdown

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

Hi here is a snipit of code...the idea is that it runs for 20 secs then at 5 seconds before 0 it plays one sound then at end of countdown plays the next...but it is just playing the end and skipping the 5 sec mark...I have tried playing with it but can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

```
//Counter 2
final CountDownTimer counter2 = new CountDownTimer(20000 , 1000) {
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
  mCounter2TextField.setText(" " + formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

  long timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

  if (timeLeft == 5000) 
         playAlertSound(R.drawable.sound1);

}

public void onFinish() {
  start();
  playSound();
}

public void playSound() {
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), (R.drawable.sound2));
mp.start();

}   


};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's cause your :

```
playSound(...);
```

Is in the same 'thread' as your Timer. You should just do somthing like :

```
if (timeLeft == 5000) 

  new Runnable(){
      void Run(){
           playAlertSound(R.drawable.sound1);
      }
      public void playSound() {
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), (R.drawable.sound2));
            mp.start();
       }

  }.run();
```

Or something like that :D

Cause you cant decrease your Timer and play sound at same time ! :)

Comment: +1, this is the main problem. Some simpler problems addressed by my answer, but this is what's really happening.

Comment: Saw your comment, and yes you'r right too... He's trying to compare 2 values that won't ever match.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting `millisUntilFinished` to seconds in `timeLeft`, and then telling it to only play if there are 5000 seconds (not milliseconds) left.

As you're making the change to fix that, you should also change the comparison to `timeLeft <= 5` so it will begin playing if `onTick` is called with `4999` milliseconds left. You'll, of course, need to add logic to not play the sound if it's already been started playing.

Comment: I have even tried 5 instead of 5000 still didn't work hence the 5000 was a final try before asking you chaps...

Comment: Even so, it needs correction. Also, check the second paragraph of my post. The main problem is addressed by Cehm's answer.

Comment: @Djorn: It is highly unlikely that `onTick` will be called at EXACTLY 5000 milliseconds depending on what else is going on in the system. It may be called at 5005ms of 4095ms or anywhere in between or even +/- either of those values.